# How to acess path permission in Express nodejs?

Tags: html, node.js, express

I am completely new in express node.js . I have a folder structure like :

```
/Express 
   --server.js
   --index.html
   --home.html
      /css/
      /js/
      /images
      /fonts
```

In `index.html` i am accessing some `javascript (js folder)` , `images (images folder)` , `fonts (fonts folder)` . Also i am linking `home.html` from `index.html` page . I need to block accessing `home.html` directly also .

I wrote a `server.js` with `express-ws` like this :

```
  var express = require('express');
  var app = express();
  var expressWs = require('express-ws')(app);
  var path = require('path');

  //accessing index.html
  app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));

   });

   //How can i acess all the files inside the JS , CSS , Image and Font folder here ???  

    //Also How can i link home.html from Index.html File and block home.html accessing publicly  

   app.ws('/', function(ws, req) {
      ws.on('message', function(msg) {
       console.log(msg);
      });
      console.log('socket', req.testing);
    });

  app.listen(8888);
```

Any suggestions how can i access all the files inside the JS , CSS , Image and Font folder from `index.html` with `server.js` ? Also linking `home.html` from `index.html` with direct access block  .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a separate folder for static content like `public` or anything else and then use `express.static()` to serve static content. So here would be your updated directory structure

```
/Express 
   --server.js
   --index.html
   --home.html
   --/public/ (directory)
          --/css/ (directory)
          --/js/ (directory)
          --/images/ (directory)
          --/fonts/ (directory)
```

and your updated code would be

```
  var express = require('express');
  var app = express();
  var expressWs = require('express-ws')(app);
  var path = require('path');

  //for js, css, images and fonts
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

  //accessing index.html
  app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));

   });

   app.ws('/', function(ws, req) {
      ws.on('message', function(msg) {
       console.log(msg);
      });
      console.log('socket', req.testing);
    });

  app.listen(8888);
```

Comment: I don't see how  `app.use(path.join(__dirname, express.static('public')));` can possibly be proper syntax.  `express.static()` returns a middleware function.  Why would you pass a middleware function to `path.join()`?

Comment: thanks @jfriend00, I have updated code, that was typo error

Comment: But i didn't get redirection to 'home.html' when i click a link in 'index.html' . Should i link that HTML  also  ? Also that home.html is using some css , js folders . I think i should put home.html inside public folder .

Comment: @user2986042 if you put `home.html` in public folder then it cat be access directly like http://localhost:8888/home.html

Comment: i resolved it . i didn't change files . Instead of add  `app.get('/home.html')`  etc ..  Thanks again .. it worked

Answer (score 1):

add following after requiring path

```
// serve index.css at localhost:3000/index.css
app.use(express.static('css')); // looks in current directory for css folder

// serve index.js at localhost:3000/static/index.js
app.use('/static', express.static('js')); // looks in current directory for js folder and appends /static to URL

app.use(express.static('fonts'));
```

[Reference on serving static files from express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: Thanks .. i will check